Ansible - set individual user passwords from a predefined table
I have to set a big bunch of passwords on a reasonable group of hosts. I have a table in colon separated form, containing lines in hostname:username:pwhash format.
Here is an example (passwords here are generated with Crypt, in real life they are bigger)
host1:johna:cE4GOpMpD8UKo
host1:madison:vtVdl93sgCHzQ
host1:peterd:S0MOKx0IuuIh2
host1:bollner:LfQXomajqjq3k
host2:madison:wPIjAoVHlkL/U
host2:johna7djh.TZsGLjkk
host2:annew:ujMvwlBf8AsSA
host2:weakid:YbJf32HHdKKc2
host2:romeo:Uiq4z9VjrcDHg
host2:bollner:y4.QCu5O84YAo
host3:annew:2ACF6MyVHLz12
host3:johna:wdX/AecZosQY2
host3:peterd:DjicQXCGAfNSQ
host3:bollner:iDLBoU.WQOEM.

I would like to create an Ansible playbook whic would read the above table format, or maybe converted to yml into entries like
item1:
  host: host1
  user: bollner
  pwhash: DjicQXCGAfNSQ

or similar and place it in a dict type variable. But how could I iterate through it? I could not find out how to select the relevant items by host.
Most probably I would use user module to set the passwords, but I would need to select only users which already exist on the goven host.
Oh, and one heavy constraint: Ansible version 2.4.1.0 - and for some reasons I am not allowed to upgrade it.
Any help would be highly apperciated!

Have you looked at from csv filter

RedHat has a nice article on this 4 steps to create Linux users from a csv file with Ansible.  You will just need to tweak it with a when to check if the ansible host name is equal to the hostname in the list.

Using the from_csv filter referenced in the previous comment, you could do something as simple as when: item.hostname == inventory_hostname, or you could use something like selectattr to extract only those users that match the current host.

Why are you closing this? It is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development (parse structure, select items, iterate subelements).

@VladimirBotka, indeed, in my opinion we should not close this question.

@Squashman - I am tied to Ansible version 2.4 and it says no such filter. Life is hard between ancient software components.

Read the file
    - community.general.read_csv:
        path: data.csv
        fieldnames: node,user,pswd
        delimiter: ':'
      register: out
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true

and "instantiate" data for all hosts
    - set_fact:
        data: "{{ dict(nodes|zip(users)) }}"
      vars:
        nodes: "{{ out.list | groupby('node') | map('first') }}"
        users: "{{ out.list | groupby('node') | map('last') }}"
      run_once: true

gives
  data:
    host1:
    - {node: host1, pswd: cE4GOpMpD8UKo, user: johna}
    - {node: host1, pswd: vtVdl93sgCHzQ, user: madison}
    - {node: host1, pswd: S0MOKx0IuuIh2, user: peterd}
    - {node: host1, pswd: LfQXomajqjq3k, user: bollner}
    host2:
    - {node: host2, pswd: wPIjAoVHlkL/U, user: madison}
    - {node: host2, pswd: null, user: johna7djh.TZsGLjkk}
    - {node: host2, pswd: ujMvwlBf8AsSA, user: annew}
    - {node: host2, pswd: YbJf32HHdKKc2, user: weakid}
    - {node: host2, pswd: Uiq4z9VjrcDHg, user: romeo}
    - {node: host2, pswd: y4.QCu5O84YAo, user: bollner}
    host3:
    - {node: host3, pswd: 2ACF6MyVHLz12, user: annew}
    - {node: host3, pswd: wdX/AecZosQY2, user: johna}
    - {node: host3, pswd: DjicQXCGAfNSQ, user: peterd}
    - {node: host3, pswd: iDLBoU.WQOEM., user: bollner}

Select the node and iterate users
    - debug:
        msg: "[{{ inventory_hostname }}] Create user:{{ item.user }} pswd:{{ item.pswd }}"
      loop: "{{ data[inventory_hostname] | d([]) }}"

gives abridged
ok: [host1] => (item={'node': 'host1', 'user': 'johna', 'pswd': 'cE4GOpMpD8UKo'}) => 
  msg: '[host1] Create user:johna pswd:cE4GOpMpD8UKo'
ok: [host2] => (item={'node': 'host2', 'user': 'madison', 'pswd': 'wPIjAoVHlkL/U'}) => 
  msg: '[host2] Create user:madison pswd:wPIjAoVHlkL/U'
ok: [host1] => (item={'node': 'host1', 'user': 'madison', 'pswd': 'vtVdl93sgCHzQ'}) => 
  msg: '[host1] Create user:madison pswd:vtVdl93sgCHzQ'
ok: [host1] => (item={'node': 'host1', 'user': 'peterd', 'pswd': 'S0MOKx0IuuIh2'}) => 
  msg: '[host1] Create user:peterd pswd:S0MOKx0IuuIh2'
ok: [host2] => (item={'node': 'host2', 'user': 'johna7djh.TZsGLjkk', 'pswd': None}) => 
  msg: '[host2] Create user:johna7djh.TZsGLjkk pswd:'
ok: [host2] => (item={'node': 'host2', 'user': 'annew', 'pswd': 'ujMvwlBf8AsSA'}) => 
  msg: '[host2] Create user:annew pswd:ujMvwlBf8AsSA'
ok: [host3] => (item={'node': 'host3', 'user': 'annew', 'pswd': '2ACF6MyVHLz12'}) => 
  msg: '[host3] Create user:annew pswd:2ACF6MyVHLz12'
ok: [host1] => (item={'node': 'host1', 'user': 'bollner', 'pswd': 'LfQXomajqjq3k'}) => 
  msg: '[host1] Create user:bollner pswd:LfQXomajqjq3k'
ok: [host2] => (item={'node': 'host2', 'user': 'weakid', 'pswd': 'YbJf32HHdKKc2'}) => 
  msg: '[host2] Create user:weakid pswd:YbJf32HHdKKc2'
ok: [host3] => (item={'node': 'host3', 'user': 'johna', 'pswd': 'wdX/AecZosQY2'}) => 
  msg: '[host3] Create user:johna pswd:wdX/AecZosQY2'
ok: [host3] => (item={'node': 'host3', 'user': 'peterd', 'pswd': 'DjicQXCGAfNSQ'}) => 
  msg: '[host3] Create user:peterd pswd:DjicQXCGAfNSQ'
ok: [host2] => (item={'node': 'host2', 'user': 'romeo', 'pswd': 'Uiq4z9VjrcDHg'}) => 
  msg: '[host2] Create user:romeo pswd:Uiq4z9VjrcDHg'
ok: [host2] => (item={'node': 'host2', 'user': 'bollner', 'pswd': 'y4.QCu5O84YAo'}) => 
  msg: '[host2] Create user:bollner pswd:y4.QCu5O84YAo'
ok: [host3] => (item={'node': 'host3', 'user': 'bollner', 'pswd': 'iDLBoU.WQOEM.'}) => 
  msg: '[host3] Create user:bollner pswd:iDLBoU.WQOEM.'



Example of a complete playbook for testing
- hosts: all

  tasks:

    - block:

        - community.general.read_csv:
            path: data.csv
            fieldnames: node,user,pswd
            delimiter: ':'
          register: out
          delegate_to: localhost

        - set_fact:
            data: "{{ dict(nodes|zip(users)) }}"
          vars:
            nodes: "{{ out.list | groupby('node') | map('first') }}"
            users: "{{ out.list | groupby('node') | map('last') }}"

        - debug:
            var: data | to_yaml

      run_once: true

    - debug:
        msg: "[{{ inventory_hostname }}] Create user:{{ item.user }} pswd:{{ item.pswd }}"
      loop: "{{ data[inventory_hostname] | d([]) }}"


Q: "Constraint: Ansible version 2.4" (read_csv module appears is Ansible version 2.8)
A: Parse the CSV file on your own. Use the filter community.general.dict and create the list of  dictionaries
  - set_fact:
      out: "{{ lookup('file', 'data.csv') |
               split |
               map('split', ':') |
               map('zip', ['node', 'user', 'pswd']) |
               map('map', 'reverse') |
               map('community.general.dict') }}"

gives
  out:
    - {node: host1, pswd: cE4GOpMpD8UKo, user: johna}
    - {node: host1, pswd: vtVdl93sgCHzQ, user: madison}
    - {node: host1, pswd: S0MOKx0IuuIh2, user: peterd}
    - {node: host1, pswd: LfQXomajqjq3k, user: bollner}
    - {node: host2, pswd: wPIjAoVHlkL/U, user: madison}
    - {node: host2, pswd: 7djh.TZsGLjkk, user: johna}
    - {node: host2, pswd: ujMvwlBf8AsSA, user: annew}
    - {node: host2, pswd: YbJf32HHdKKc2, user: weakid}
    - {node: host2, pswd: Uiq4z9VjrcDHg, user: romeo}
    - {node: host2, pswd: y4.QCu5O84YAo, user: bollner}
    - {node: host3, pswd: 2ACF6MyVHLz12, user: annew}
    - {node: host3, pswd: wdX/AecZosQY2, user: johna}
    - {node: host3, pswd: DjicQXCGAfNSQ, user: peterd}
    - {node: host3, pswd: iDLBoU.WQOEM., user: bollner}

Example of a complete playbook for testing
- hosts: all

  tasks:

    - block:

        - set_fact:
            out: "{{ lookup('file', 'data.csv') |
                     split |
                     map('split', ':') |
                     map('zip', ['node', 'user', 'pswd']) |
                     map('map', 'reverse') |
                     map('community.general.dict') }}"

        - debug:
            var: out | to_yaml

        - set_fact:
            data: "{{ dict(nodes|zip(users)) }}"
          vars:
            nodes: "{{ out | groupby('node') | map('first') }}"
            users: "{{ out | groupby('node') | map('last') }}"

        - debug:
            var: data | to_yaml

      run_once: true

    - debug:
        msg: "[{{ inventory_hostname }}] Create user:{{ item.user }} pswd:{{ item.pswd }}"
      loop: "{{ data[inventory_hostname] | d([]) }}"



Thanks a lot. Anyways, read_csv module appears is Ansible version 2.8 and I am locked to 2.4. But I can avoid csv input with include_vars - and appropriately formatted data file. Trying that direction.

I missed this constraint, sorry. Parse the file on your own. I added an example.
